# what is the most pratical way to create cross platform standalone tiny gui tool?

Tags: windows, user-interface, unix, cross-platform

What is the  the most pratical way  ( or programming language to use ) , to create a tiny standalone , single page , static gui tool ?

Comment: If  you are not a developer, the fastest way would be hiring some developers... anyway this kind of request is off-topic on SO

Comment: sorry , i meant 'best' not 'fastest' , i am a c++ programmer for 7 years now , and i am building a build system for my game engine , thats why i am asking

Comment: i will glad if you remove the down vote

Comment: _i meant 'best' not 'fastest'..._ And now it seems the answer on that question would be opinion based.... I can't remove the dv it isn't mine

Comment: Simplest would be html/js, but this won't be standalone. You can try to have a look at `cordova` or `gtk` I didn't downvote also! Peoples here are sometimes very arrogant...

Comment: @B001ᛦ i knew you will say it will be opinion based , sorry , any suggestions will be approciated

Comment: Also, to embed html/js as standalone, you can have a look at `nw.js` or `electron` . It will works fairly easily, but your standalone program will weight over 100mb...

Comment: [Qt](https://www.qt.io/)

Comment: Xojo is another option to make standalone, native, cross-platform apps for Windows, macOS and Linux. http://www.xojo.com

Answer (score 1):

Lazarus is a Rapid Application Development Tool for Free Pascal.
It comes with the LCL - Lazarus component library, which contains platform
independent visual components like buttons, windows, checkbox, treeview and
many, many more. The LCL is platform independent, so you can write an
application once and then compile for various platforms without changing code.

Lazarus comes with a drag and drop IDE + code editor

Lazarus uses object pascal , it is crossplatform , and it's exported executables are standalone

So yes Lazarus  is the answer